# Achieve Unique Column Width for each Cell in Different Rows with a GridPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to model credit card data in `JavaFx` using a `GridPane`:

My model contains 3 rows (Note: each field is comprised of label + text field):

**Row 1**: First name and last name (4 fields)

**Row 2**: Credit card number (2 fields)

**Row 3**: Expiration date - month, year + CVV (6 fields)

See screenshot below:

[image: Card Data Model]

I was reading [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/gridpane.html) which states:

> All cells in the same row will have the same height, and all cells in
> the same column will have the same width. Different rows can have
> different heights and different columns can have different widths.

Are there any workarounds to to have different size columns on a row by row basis in a `GridPane`?

Comment: That specific design looks as though three `HBox`s placed in a `VBox` would work better. You might be able to achieve the same using some clever application of column spans too.

Comment: @James_D Sounds like you're onto something good. Can you expound a bit on what you mean by  _You might be able to achieve the same using some clever application of column spans too_ Perhaps as a full fledged answer? Thanks!!

Comment: Next time I’m back at a computer I’ll test it out.

Comment: I advise using SceneBuilder to create more complex layouts like this rather than writing them in code.

Comment: just an aside: hope this form is not intended for usage in a real application: it's broken from a ui design perspective ;) Needing many unrelated column/row spans nearly always is a clear warning sign. When it flashes, it's time do some research into the designer scene, there are options :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the specific layout in the image, I would use a `VBox` with `HBox` for rows:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Label lblFirst = new Label("First");
        Label lblLast = new Label("Last");
        Label lblNumber = new Label("Card Number");
        Label lblMonth = new Label("Month");
        Label lblYear = new Label("Year");
        Label lblCVV = new Label("CVV");
        
        TextField txtFirst = new TextField();
        TextField txtLast = new TextField();
        TextField txtNumber = new TextField();
        TextField txtMonth = new TextField();
        TextField txtYear = new TextField();
        TextField txtCVV = new TextField();

        HBox row1 = new HBox(10);
        HBox row2 = new HBox(10);
        HBox row3 = new HBox(10);
        
        row1.getChildren().add(createCell(lblFirst, txtFirst));
        row1.getChildren().add(createCell(lblLast, txtLast));
        
        row2.getChildren().add(createCell(lblNumber, txtNumber));
        
        row3.getChildren().add(createCell(lblMonth, txtMonth));
        row3.getChildren().add(createCell(lblYear, txtYear));
        row3.getChildren().add(createCell(lblCVV, txtCVV));
        
        VBox rows = new VBox(10, row1, row2, row3);
        
        StackPane.setMargin(rows, new Insets(10));
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane(rows);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static HBox createCell(Label label, TextField text) {
        HBox pane = new HBox(5, label, text);
        label.setMinWidth(Pane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        text.setMinWidth(50);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setHgrow(text, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: don't hard-code sizing hints

Answer (score 5):

+1 for what @JamesD suggested and @Oboe answer. Ideally I would separate each row layout, to handle it in easy way than making it complex using only one GridPane.

Having said that, if you want to go with or learn about how you can do the similar layouting using one GridPane, the below implemenation may give you a quick idea.

Firstly split your layout into the required columns, to figure out how many total columns you need. (as in the below image)

[image]

Now you will know which node will sit in which column and how many columns it will occupy (colspan)

I will explain for one node:

Lets say you want insert the field of first name. If you notice in the picture, it is in rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 1 and it is occupying  4 columns, so the colSpan value will be 4. Here we are not combining any rows, so the rowSpan value will be always 1.

```
pane.add(getField(), 1, 0, 4, 1); // node, colIndex, rowIndex, colSpan, rowSpan
```

Similarly you can relate the rest of the nodes layouting. And also for more precising you can set the prefered width of each column using ColumnConstraints. Below is the complete code for the layout & constraints:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CreditCardPaneDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setSpacing(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,300,200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("CreditCard");
        stage.show();

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-background-color:yellow");
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        pane.setHgap(5);
        pane.setVgap(5);

        pane.add(getLabel("First"), 0, 0, 1, 1);
        pane.add(getField(), 1, 0, 4, 1);
        pane.add(getLabel("Last"), 5, 0, 1, 1);
        pane.add(getField(), 6, 0, 2, 1);

        pane.add(getLabel("Card Number"), 0, 1, 3, 1);
        pane.add(getField(), 3, 1, 5, 1);

        pane.add(getLabel("Month"), 0, 2, 2, 1);
        pane.add(getField(), 2, 2, 2, 1);
        pane.add(getLabel("Year"), 4, 2, 1, 1);
        pane.add(getField(), 5, 2, 1, 1);
        pane.add(getLabel("CVV"), 6, 2, 1, 1);
        pane.add(getField(), 7, 2, 1, 1);

        pane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(getCc(70), getCc(20), getCc(80), getCc(20), getCc(25), getCc(90), getCc(80), getCc(100));

        CheckBox gridLines = new CheckBox("Show grid lines");
        gridLines.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> pane.gridLinesVisibleProperty().set(val));
        root.getChildren().addAll(gridLines, pane);
    }

    private ColumnConstraints getCc(double width) {
        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc.setPrefWidth(width);
        return cc;
    }

    private Label getLabel(String txt) {
        Label lbl = new Label(txt);
        lbl.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        return lbl;
    }

    private TextField getField() {
        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        return field;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't hard-code sizing hints

Comment: @kleopatra, thanks for the suggestion. If I understand correctly, you are mentioning about usage of USE_PREF_SIZE & MAX_VALUE. right? If yes, can you please suggest the alternate for using them as I couldnt find a way to ensure the Label's have the min width to not show "..." and the text boxes to auto stretch the available space. If no, can you explain a bit about the hints you are talking about.

Comment: no, I meant the hard-coded real numbers passed into `getCc` - the sentinels defined in Region are okay as are bounderies of the number spectrum :)

Comment: but then, this layout is pathologic from a visual design perspective - it's breaking each and every single rule as to how to design a good user interface. So hope it's just an exercise to learn usage and limitations of gridpane ;)